# Haskell: implementation issues of some basic features

Tags: programming-languages

I'm taking a "Programming Language: Design and Implementation" course and our professor asked to make a case study about: Haskell programming language. In this case study he asks to make a report about: "implementation issues of some basic features. Can anybody list any good sources for this?

Comment: Have you tried to find any sources on this?

Comment: @DaveClarke Yea, I've tried, but I couldn't find the exact thing I'm searching for.

Comment: Look for "Simon Peyton Jones". He is the primary implementor of GHC, arguably the main Haskell implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) cites a wide range of sources and has a decent "Further reading" section.

Comment: looked into them, but can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: You looked at *all* of them? There are nearly sixty links, a technical report, seven books and a paper. *None* of those contained anything useful? In that case, you must have extremely specific requirements and those are in no way communicated in your question.